# CurrentImage crashing Mathematica kernel

Tags: image-processing, crash

Frequently, but not always, when I start up Mma and then evaluate

```
CurrentImage[]
```

I get a light blue box with the content

```
"Updating from Wolfram Research Server (0%)"
```

The percentage never increases, and after a minute or two the kernel dies with a beep.
This is new behavior for me. Has anyone else seen this and is there a fix or workaround?

I am on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) with macOS 10.12.4 and Mma 11.0.1.

Comment: 1) Upgrade to 11.1, I think there were a lot of updates to it there 2) if it persists, contact support

Comment: It works for me, same OS, same hardware, same Mathematica version. So there has to be a fix without upgrading to 11.1.

Comment: Have you tried basic things like fully restarting Mathematica (not just the kernel)?

Comment: I had tried restarting Mma, and indeed the whole computer, but it did not cure the problem. Just now I upgraded to 11.1, and the problem is gone, at least for now. If it recurs I will post a note.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with my frequent use of an external display (LG thunderbolt display) but I had the problem even when disconnected. (I know about $DisplayDevices).

Comment: I think the relevant one here is `$ImagingDevice` and `$ImagingDevices`.  EDIT: Oh, I think that's what you actually meant by `$DisplayDevices`.

Comment: Same problem on one of my computers, on version 10.3 to 11.0, it should be a system dependent bug.